# OpenSSH server doesn't work on Windows Server 2019

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2019

I have a problem with OpenSSH server.

1. I downloaded https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases OpenSSH-Win64
2. extracted it in C:\OpenSSH-Win64
3. ran install-sshd.ps1
4. changed OpenSSH server & Authenticate Agent to automatic and started it
5. added inbound rule for firewall port 22
6. added OpenSSH folder to path variable.

On the server I can login into ssh but on another computer I can't:

```
ssh: connect to host xxxxxxx port 22: Connection timed out.
```

I tried to connect with open RDP connection and without it and I can't ping this server (don't know if this can be problem). Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault.  Are those two systems on the same network?

Comment: No, they are in two diffrent networks.

Comment: Then that's the thing.  You need to ensure that 1) the routing is ok; that is, system A can ping your Win2019 server.  2) Ensure in your Win2019 Server that the firewall rule is also not set to Blocking Edge Traversal.  But I think the *main* item is the routing issue.

Comment: Ok, so that's the thing. Pings are blocked in the firewall (i guess they are afraid of ddos or something) and i'm not sure that im allowed to off this rule. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Well, if pings are blocked in the firewall/router setup, then you will need to contact whoever is in charge of that setup and ask them if they can allow a route between the ssh client system and the server.  That's the only thing I can think of.